# Flask-Dance: No module named 'flask_dance.consumer.backend'

Tags: python, flask, flask-dance

That's my very first question here, please don't eat me! I am totally newbie, I try to write a flask app using flask-dance for `OAuth` reason. Seems I do something stupid, because when I try to `import SQLAlchemyBackend class from flask_dance.consumer.backend.sqla` Python returns

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_dance.consumer.backend'

Can you tell me please what exactly I do wrong?

I use flask-dance[sqla] version for SQLAlchemy db. First I installed basic version without SQLAlchemy support, then I uninstalled it and installed current one (all inside the venv). Is it possible that that affected the F-D functionality and its own modules and submodules scheme?

I have no idea how to fix that problem and where to go. Google doesn't help neither.

What I see in the trackback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\users\igor\envs\2do2\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)   File "C:\Users\igor\projects\gp\2do2\app\app.py", line 8, in <module>
    from flask_dance.consumer.backend.sqla import SQLAlchemyBackend ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_dance.consumer.backend'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [Flask-Dance 1.4.0](https://github.com/singingwolfboy/flask-dance/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#140-2019-02-22), "backends" were renamed to "storages", since the word "backend" means something different in the context of web development. This change was backwards-compatible in 1.4.0, but the backwards-compatibility features were dropped in [Flask-Dance 2.0.0](https://github.com/singingwolfboy/flask-dance/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#200-2019-03-30).

To make this work in Flask 2.0 and above, just replace the word "backend" with the word "storage" everywhere you see it. For example, this line of code:

```py
from flask_dance.consumer.backend.sqla import SQLAlchemyBackend
```

becomes this instead:

```py
from flask_dance.consumer.storage.sqla import SQLAlchemyStorage
```

If you see any references to "backends" in the [current documentation](https://flask-dance.readthedocs.io), please let me know! They should all be "storages" now.